# Receiving error The parameters (number[]) don't match the method signature for SpreadsheetApp.Range.setValues

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a list of arrays that I am trying to paste in a Google Spreadsheet. However, I am receiving an error:

> The parameters (number[]) don't match the method signature for SpreadsheetApp.Range.setValues

When I check my `console.log(array1.length)` it outputs `32`, which is correct.
What am I missing?

```
function userClickedRoster(array2)
{

 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('19xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxUOI');
 var sheet1 = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet2');
 var array1 = sheet1.getRange("K1:K" + sheet1.getLastRow()).getValues();
 var array3 = sheet1.getRange("N1:N" + sheet1.getLastRow()).getValues();
 var array4 = sheet1.getRange("O1:O" + sheet1.getLastRow()).getValues();

  array2.forEach((el) => {
  array1[el[0]] = el[1]; array3[el[0]]=el[2]; array4[el[0]]=el[3];
})

 sheet1.getRange(1, 11, array1.length, 1).setValues(array1);
 sheet1.getRange(1, 14, array3.length, 1).setValues(array3);
 sheet1.getRange(1, 15, array4.length, 1).setValues(array4);

  console.log(array1.length);
  console.log(array1);
 }
```

Comment: What type does setValues() expect according to the documentation?

Comment: setValues accepts array and setValue accept single element.

Comment: Array yes. What type of array?

Comment: the link you provided says 2d array. So i have to convert my 1D array to 2D array. by using ([array1]). How do I convert 1D array to 2D.

Comment: Yes that'll work, if range width === array.length. It provides direction too. If you want to set a 1D array to  range height, use `.map(e=>[e])`. Alternatively, change the logic during the creation/modification of those arrays.

Comment: I'll let you figure it out.